# How to set a category to all objects

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic

I have a fixed number of categories:

> 1, 2 and 3

And I have N elements in an array.

I want to set the category of each element, where the first third is to be = 3, second third to be = 2 and the last third is to be = 1.

I am using this humble code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length / 3 - 1; i++) // set first 3rd
    data[i].category = 3;

for(let j = parseInt(data.length / 3); j < (data.length * 2)/3 - 1; j++) // set 2nd third 
    data[i].category = 2; 

for(let k = parseInt((data.length * 2)/3); k < data.length; k++) // set 3rd third
    data[i].category = 1;
```

But that does not give accurate results especially when N is < 3.

If N < 3, I want:

> If N=1, set it to 3
>
> If N=2, set first element to 3, second to 2
>
> If N=3, set first to 3, second to 2 and third to 1
>
> If N=4, set first to 3, second to 2 and last two to 1
>
> If N=5, set first to 3, second two to 2, last two to 1
>
> If N=6, split to three thirds and assign a category to each couple
>
> .. etc

So if N is odd, last item belongs to category = 1 (last category)... etc. But confusion is when N is odd and N-1 is not divisible by 3 (example N=11: I would want first 3 to be 3, then 4 to be 2 and last 4 to be 1). Or when N is even but not divisible by 3 (example N=8: I would want first 2 to be 3, then 3 to be 2 and last 3 to be 1)

How can I achieve that? solution can be in any programming language and I will then convert it to javascript

Comment: Your conditions seem to be underspecified. I can't figure out what you mean by "etc." For example is N = 7 supposed to map to 3332211 or 3322211 or 3322111? Or ... ?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am really flexible with the answer of your last question, N=7 can be any (3332211 or 3322211 or 3322111) if the code is "cleaner" -> simpler to read and to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this bit of Python will help:

```
def f(n):
    q,r = divmod(n,3) #quotient and remainder
    a = q
    b = q + (1 if r == 2 else 0)
    c = q + (1 if r > 0 else 0)
    return (a,b,c)
```

Used like:

```
>>> for N in range(1,15): print(N, "=>",f(N))

1 => (0, 0, 1)
2 => (0, 1, 1)
3 => (1, 1, 1)
4 => (1, 1, 2)
5 => (1, 2, 2)
6 => (2, 2, 2)
7 => (2, 2, 3)
8 => (2, 3, 3)
9 => (3, 3, 3)
10 => (3, 3, 4)
11 => (3, 4, 4)
12 => (4, 4, 4)
13 => (4, 4, 5)
14 => (4, 5, 5)
```

Note that `(1 if r == 2 else 0)` is like `r == 2 ? 1 : 0` in C-syntax languages.

The interpretation of the output `(i,j,k)` is that the first `i` elements in the array are set equal to `3`, the next `j` elements are set equal to `2` and the final `k` elements are set equal to `3`. Your question seemed to be how to get this way of splitting `N`.

Comment: `divmod` simultaneously computes integer quotient and remainder, so `q = int(n/3)` and `r = n%3`

Answer (score 2):

You could take a correction for small arrays and calculate the value for the wanted parts.

```js
var array = [
        [1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    ],
    result = array.map(aa => aa.map(
        (_, i, a) => (a.length < 3 && 3 - a.length) + (i < Math.floor(a.length / 3) ? 3 : 1 + (i < Math.floor(2 * a.length / 3)))
    ));
    
console.log(result.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```